# Using styles of the iOS system font other than Regular in code

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, fonts, uifont

At the moment I know I can use `[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]` to set the font of a `UILabel` to the system font. But how would I retrieve the medium style of the system font programmatically? There only seems to see a method with the regular style of the font to be applied.

At the moment I can only seem to use these fonts in IB:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "medium" and "regular" version of the font? Please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`+systemFontOfSize:weight:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/systemFontOfSize:weight:), with one of the [font weight constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFontDescriptor_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Font_Weights) from UIFontDescriptor.

Or, perhaps more appropriately, [`preferredFontForTextStyle:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIFont/preferredFontForTextStyle:) which respects the user's settings.